# pygame - How to make a circle move based on a dice roll?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to get a circle to move based on a dice roll of 1-5.

Eg. if it rolls a 4, it will move the circle to a total of 580 - (55 * 4) pixels.

However I can't make it so the circle will basically clear the old version of itself dynamically, any ideas?

Also, I am trying to make it so the prompt message saying what number on the dice you have rolled clear itself after the user has seen it. so like pressing a button to make the program know that you have seen the dice number and wishes to proceed, however I can't do that without clearing the entire game window and when the game window clears, it will forget the old circle coordinates which makes the counters move back to the starting position again...

What I've attempted as requested -

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:

            diceRoll = random.randint(1,5)
            diceAlert = font.render("You rolled a: "+str(diceRoll), True, red)
            moveCounter = font.render("Please click 1 or 2 to select the counter", True, red)

            screen.blit(diceAlert, [665, 35])
            screen.blit(moveCounter, [665, 70])
            pygame.display.update()


        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_1:

            if diceRoll == 1:
                cover = int(0)
            if diceRoll == 2:
                cover = int(2)
            if diceRoll == 3:
                cover = int(2)
            if diceRoll == 4:
                cover = int(3)

            counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (250, 580-(cover*55)), 15, 0)

            counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (250, var[0]-55*diceRoll), 15, 0)

            window()

            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Sure. I'll add some code in the question.

Comment: what does `window()` do?

Comment: High there. Sorry about the confusion.

window() calls the function in which the grid is drawn for the circle. I put it there to re-draw the entire board to make the counters seem to "move".

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be bliting a circle only if a button has been pressed. This forces you to use your screen, as your only information of the state of your game. Instead you should separate those 2.

Here is a template of a pygame game:

```
init()
while not finished:
    draw()
    update()
    input()
```

These 4 functions do different things. You should not do any drawing in the input method.

Let's go through these functions:

`init()` initializes pygame, screen, loads files, and creates any instances that are needed. In your case here you can create a variable that will store the current circle position.

`draw()` clears the screen with fill(), and draws all the sprites on screen. In your case, his will the the circle position, and draw it accordingly.

`update()` this updates sprites on the screen, checks collisions etc. You don't have anything that will use this function, since your game is static, it does not change in time.

`input()` takes input, and changes the state of objects. In your case, you would test to see if a button was pressed, and if so, change the circle position.

After tidying up your code it will look like this:

```
circle_pos = (0,0)
circle_pos2 = (0,0)
while True:
    screen.blit(diceAlert, [665, 35])
    screen.blit(moveCounter, [665, 70])            
    counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, circle_pos, 15, 0)
    counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, circle_pos2, 15, 0)

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:

            diceRoll = random.randint(1,5)
            diceAlert = font.render("You rolled a: "+str(diceRoll), True, red)
            moveCounter = font.render("Please click 1 or 2 to select the counter", True, red)

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_1:

            if diceRoll == 1:
                cover = int(0)
            if diceRoll in (2,3):
                cover = int(2)
            if diceRoll == 4:
                cover = int(3)
            circle_pos = (250, 580-(cover*55))
```

The code is not fully functional, since I did not know what you are trying to accomplish. I hope this template will get you going.

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your response - Basically what I am trying to achieve is to make the previous counter clear itself once the counter has moved (re-drawn itself)/ I can't seem to think of a way to do this without  re-drawing the ENTIRE screen which will result into the program forgetting the new coordinates of the counter. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: still not clear for me. I assume we are talking about the circle yes? If so, you can store the position of the circle in a separate variable as I did in my answer, and modify this position instead. Clearing the whole screen with screen.fill() will not affect the variable.

Comment: Yes it is about the circle.

I will try it now, thanks.