# pygame - re-draw a circle based on an event

Tags: pygame, python-3.3

I'm trying to make a circle move based on a event (dice roll). Basically if the dice rolls a 1, the counter moves up 1 etc.

However I can't get the counter to move properly as it leaves the old counter there. I've tried taking away 55 pixels times by the dice roll to re-draw a white version of the counter to make it seem like it's gone. But it just doesn't seem to work. Here's a snippet of code:

```
while True:

    screen.blit(moveCounter, [665, 70])            
    counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, circle_pos, 15, 0)
    counter1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, circle_pos2, 15, 0)

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:

            diceRoll = random.randint(1,5)
            diceAlert = font.render("You rolled a: "+str(diceRoll), True, red)
            moveCounter = font.render("Please click 1 or 2 to select the counter", True, red)

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_1:

            if diceRoll == 1:
                cover = int(0)
            if diceRoll in (2,3):
                cover = int(2)
            if diceRoll == 4:
                cover = int(3)
            circle_pos = (250, 580-(cover*55))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pygame - How to make a circle move based on a dice roll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341927/pygame-how-to-make-a-circle-move-based-on-a-dice-roll)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of what @BartlomiejLewandowski said.

But yeah if you just do `screen.fill()` before you draw the new set of circles it  should remove the old instances and replace it with the new circle.

Answer (score 2):

You can `screen.fill()` with the background colour to erase everything already on the screen; see the [introductory documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html).